# SQL error - Incorrect Syntax near Keyword 'IS' - Issue with Database Name in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to execute a very simple SQL query using "Microsoft Query". I can connect to the tables, select the columns I need but when I try to execute I get error msg saying "Incorrect Syntax near keyword 'IS'"

I got the SQL statement below through automated query but it just doesn't execute successfully. I think I know what the issue is. It is because my database catalog name is "IS". I tried executing same query on my other databases with different names and it works fine.  Since I have access to several databases I need to specifiy which db I am accessing in my script and that's when it causes this issue. Is there a work around in my situation where I can avoid using database name and perhaps declare a variable?

```
SELECT Table1.id, 
Table1.Name, 
Table1.Status,
Table1.DateEntered
FROM IS.dbo.Table1 Table1
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM IS.dbo.Table1 Table1 (Same error msg)
```

Comment: Put is between brackets `[IS].dbo`

Comment: Why the MySQL tag when you are apparently using Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Look at the markup, it's clearly blue like the other system words. Your IDE should detect this too. In the future, just always use brackets.

Comment: [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Reserved Words for Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IS` is a SQL reserved keyword, you have to wrap it with `[]`

```
SELECT * FROM [IS].dbo.Table1 Table1 (Same error msg)
```

however, is a good practice - and error avoiding technique - to name tables without using reserved keywords or to always use brackets around tables name

Comment: It's even better practice to just always use brackets.

Answer (score 3):

I'd assume `IS` is a reserved keyword. Try wrapping it around square brackets:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.Name, Table1.Status, Table1.DateEntered FROM [IS].dbo.Table1 Table1
```

Comment: This is SQL Server, not `mysql`.